# Certain browsers only download instead of allowing to edit file

Tags: browser-compatibility, edit, download

SharePoint site, any kind of file (tried xlsx & txt) → can edit only from Internet Explorer (11).
Chrome, Firefox, and Opera allow only download. See bottom left option difference in attached screen shots.

Adding `OpenDocumentsReadWriteWhileBrowsing` to registry (per some blogs/forums) didn't help.

*NOTE: I think I've encountered other SharePoint sites where any browser allows editing a file. Will update post if I find that to be true.*

[image: Opening text file from IE]
[image: Opening text file from Chrome]

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking why the behaviour is happening?

Comment: It may be that the Microsoft plugin in those browsers that allows you to edit is not enabled. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is expected behavior. We tell our users that they should be using Internet Explorer whenever possible while using SharePoint. It is built to provide the most seamless experience with SharePoint. Of course this is not always the case and people have their own preferences of browser as well. We actually use chrome for most of our work but is we have to open and edit any documents we open that page up in IE before we do so.